# How do we write a condition in XSLT for the XML node that has multiple nodes within it?

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

Following is the sample XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Data_Split_File">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Flag>H</wd:Flag>
        <wd:Userid>123456</wd:Userid>
        <wd:FirstName>Alex</wd:FirstName>
        <wd:LastName>Ruther</wd:LastName>
        <wd:businessTitle>Tech Analyst</wd:businessTitle>
        <wd:WorkerType wd:Descriptor=" Support_Worker ">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">e258987456fc25845bbaf243f62fb910</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_Type_ID">Support_Worker</wd:ID>
        </wd:WorkerType>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Flag>T</wd:Flag>
        <wd:Userid>7891011</wd:Userid>
        <wd:FirstName>Wafer</wd:FirstName>
        <wd:MiddleName>Glader</wd:MiddleName>
        <wd:LastName>Tiles</wd:LastName>
        <wd:businessTitle>Tech Advisor</wd:businessTitle>
        <wd:WorkerType wd:Descriptor=" Daily_Worker ">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">e369852147fc564897bbaf243f62fb910</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_Type_ID">Daily_Worker</wd:ID>
        </wd:WorkerType>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Flag>O</wd:Flag>
        <wd:Userid>1213141</wd:Userid>
        <wd:FirstName>Federal</wd:FirstName>
        <wd:MiddleName>Mark</wd:MiddleName>
        <wd:LastName>Coupon</wd:LastName>
        <wd:businessTitle>Tech Analyst</wd:businessTitle>
        <wd:WorkerType wd:Descriptor=" Hourly_Worker ">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">e55898456fc25896bbaf243f62fb910</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_Type_ID">Hourly_Worker</wd:ID>
        </wd:WorkerType>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

I am trying to write a condition as below that filters the XML with Flag ‘O’ and worker type
‘Daily_Worker’ & ‘Hourly_Worker’,but seeing issue in filtering worker type.

```
<xsl:if test="wd:Flag ='O' or wd:WorkerType/wd:ID/wd:type=Employee_Type_ID" != ' Support_Worker '">
```

How do we filter worker type that has multiple nodes within it ?

Comment: I fixed your source XML to make it _well-formed_. If your real XML differs from that, you have to change your XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XPath expression:

```
wd:Flag='O' and (wd:WorkerType/wd:ID/@wd:type='Employee_Type_ID' or wd:WorkerType/@wd:Descriptor != ' Support_Worker ')
```

It selects all elements whose `wd:Flag` is 'O' and whose `wd:WorkerType/wd:ID/@wd:type` is 'Employee_Type_ID' or whose `wd:WorkerType/@wd:Descriptor` is not ' Support_Worker '.

So, applied to your above sample with the context node `/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry`, the result would be

```
false
false
true
```

Comment: Some how the provided Xpath expression din't work. So i have changed the xml format of that node and made changes in XSLT accordingly. Thanks